# What happens if a file is edited while open?

Tags: python, file-io

If I have a file `test.txt`, and I open it like so:

```
import time
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    time.sleep(30)
    print(f.readlines())
```

and I edit the file using a text editor in between the time when Python opens the file and when it reads the lines, what should I expect?

Should I see the lines that were there before I opened the file, or the new lines of the edited file, or is it undetermined what I'll see?

(I'm about to run these tests myself, but figured I'd ask here in case people have more information and also so that I can share my results.)

EDIT:
With some helpful comments and testing, I think I have a fairly decent understanding of what's going on, but deeper understanding would be appreciated. For example, can I edit an extremely large file near the end *while* `readlines` *is running* and have it pick up the changes? Or is the file locked inside of each individual function?

Comment: It may just be you get a dialog refusing : ```The file is locked for editing by another user.``` Since you're only reading it though with ```'r'``` not a lot may happen.

Comment: In any case the file is already read. You are just delaying printing what is already in memory.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen That's what I thought might happen as well, but that's not the results I'm getting.

Comment: Then I'm as curious as you are to see this mystery solved!

Comment: @RJAdriaansen That's actually incorrect. `f.readlines()` is a sequence which reads one line *from the file* at a time. `open` does not read the file it just prepares pyton to read it. The information is not stored in memory so the file is not read at all until a read is explicitly called on it. Storing `f.read()` in a variable will mean that all of the information has been read.

Comment: Thanks, could you put this in an answer for posterity?

Comment: I ran another test based off of @Kraigolas's comment and have included that information in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looking like the file is read from the file object's current position.

When you open the file with `with open("read_file_test.txt", "r") as f:`, Python will get the file ready for reading, and place the file object's current position at index 0.

When the file is actually read, Python will read the **most up-to-date** version of the file from that file position.

The tests that I conducted to support this are as follows:

I ran

```
import time
with open("read_file_test.txt", "r") as f:
    # gives me a countdown timer
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)
    print(f.readlines())
```

and saved the newly edited file at the 9 second mark. What was printed to the screen was the new edited text of the file.

Then, building off of @Kraigolas's suggestion, I ran:

```
import time
with open("read_file_test.txt", "r") as f:
    bar = f.read()
    print(bar)
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)
    print(f.readlines())
```

When it started, it printed the original contents of the file. I then added a new line to the file during the countdown. After the countdown was over, it printed out *only the new line that was added*, nothing else.

This led me to believe that the file object will store the character position of where it is in the file, and always read from that position in the most up-to-date version of the file.

However, if anyone knows more details or finds evidence to contradict this, I'd love to hear about it!